# TWO COLUMN "OR" query speed versus SINGLE COLUMN "DOUBLE THE ROWS" query speed

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

So let's say we have a table that contains several columns, and we index on TWO COLUMNS: *Player 1* and *Player 2*:

```
GAME   PLAYER 1    PLAYER 2   ...
====   ========    ========  
1      John        Dan
2      Carl        William
3      Carl        John
...
```

An alternate table structure indexing only on a SINGLE COLUMN: *Player 1* (and with double the rows):

```
GAME   PLAYER 1    PLAYER 2   ...
====   ========    ========  
1      John        Dan
1      Dan         John
2      Carl        William
2      William     Carl
3      Carl        John
3      John        Carl
...
```

**I want to query for all the games John played in. Which table structure/approach is better?**

Things to consider:

- This is a simplified version, and one must take into account the tables will contain at least 100's of thousands  of rows, and there will be several joins within the query.
- There will be joins on the player columns, so utilizing the TWO COLUMN approach with an "OR"/"UNION" will also double some of the joins as well.
- The SINGLE COLUMN approach will require a "GROUP BY" on the *game* column.
- We don't want to run out of memory, queries should stay running in memory!
- The TWO COLUMN approach is already getting slow, and now relies on Mysql's built-in cacheing to keep it running at a comfortable speed. I'm thinking of going to the SINGLE COLUMN approach, but unsure of the consequences.
- Another solution is to have an additional table with *Player* and *Game(foreign key)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple case, with an index on both columns you are going to be essentially doubling the table size anyways with the Index.

If there are more than 2 player columns though, the second approach will have a number of rows equal to the number of games **to the power** of the number of player columns, while the index approach will just have the number of games **multiplied by** the number of player columns for index space.

Either way, to improve performance, it would be best to replace the names with IDs that reference the players' names in another table.

Also, it seems to me there might be a simpler approach.

```
GAME   PLAYER
====   ========
1      John
1      Dan
2      Carl
2      William
3      Carl
3      John
```

No need to duplicate the data. Here you can still retrieve all the players that were in game 1, and now you can more easily retrieve the games that each player is in. Here, you only need one index. This could however possibly complicate some other queries.

Comment: yeah...that's the way to go. Vertically split off the players into another table. Keep the game table with all it's columns (the heavier table) without any duplicate rows.

Comment: Yeah, the columns are actually player ID's, but in this example I guess it was easier to look at names. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to normalize the table. Have a table for players with id and put the foreign key namely player_id on the game table.
It scales much better specially if you set index on the player_ids .
It will also make future changes to users much easier.

Comment: That's kinda like saying the SINGLE COLUMN approach is better, but you are trying to reduce the size of the duplicated data to just being the 2 player columns. So that's why you vertically split them out. Right?

Comment: I think you mean, put the foreign key "game" in the players table?

Comment: I'm not sure we are saying the same thing but the optimal situation would be having the following fields in the game table 
game,player_id1,player_id2
then you have another table called players with id and name
so you can do a simple join two retrieve names.
but in this case all the player_ids can be indexed.
No don't put a foreign key on players table. players table only has info about the player. game will reference those players using id